# Image tag won't accept src

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

I am trying to make an image take a value in as a source, after the image tag (and a related radio button) has been created using JavaScript. I have discerned the following from testing and alert outputs:

- If the image src is provided at the creation of the image tag using an exact filepath, it will show the image correctly (e.g.  src='images/0.jpg'). However, this is not helpful since I need it to work for any given image, not a specific one.
- If the image src is provided at the creation of the image tag using a variable containing a filepath, it fails to generate the image tag or the radio button at all (e.g. src='" + result + '").

NOTE: The last example is not present in the code below. The result was found by moving the '$.post' section to the line directly under the 'out +=' line within the for loop.

- If the image src is left blank at the creation of the image tag, the image tag and radio button are created, though the image is blank as expected. If I then try to use 'getElementByID(imgID).src' to change the image source after this, it fails to do anything. ('imgID' here is an example, not what the code says).

On top of the above, using alerts and dumping info into divs indicate that the comicID is being correctly posted, and the filepath of the image src is definitely being found, and is being copied into the variable 'result' correctly, even one line before the creation of the tag or the attempt to edit it using 'getElementById'.

At this point I'm stumped, I don't know what could logically be stopping the src from reading in.

--

Javascript:

```
<script>
// Loads the user's comic list from the database.
        function loadComic()
        {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var getID = '<?php echo $_SESSION["userID"]; ?>';
        var url = "loadCom.php?userID="+getID;


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                loadComicJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        }

        // JSON parsing for 'loadComic'.
        function loadComicJSON(response)
        {
            var arr = JSON.parse(response);
            var i;
            var out = "";

            document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML="";

            if (arr.length == 0)
            {
                //Irrelevant manipulation of HTML.
            }
            else
            {   
                out+="<br>";

                for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                {
                    out += "<hr><br><img name = '" + ('cm' + arr[i].comicID) + "' id='" + ('com' + arr[i].comicID) + "' onclick='resizeThumb(this)' height='100px;' src='' ><input name='comicList' type='radio' id='" + arr[i].comicID + "' value='" + arr[i].comicID + "'>" + arr[i].comicName + " </option><br><br>";                        
                }


                document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML=out;
                for(j=0; j< arr.length; j++)
                {
                    tempID = (arr[j].comicID);
                    $.post("getCover.php", {comicID:tempID}, function(result)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML+="<p>"+result+"</p>";
                        document.getElementById("com"+arr[j].comicID).src = result;
                    }
                    );

                }

            }

        }

    </script>
```

PHP (getCover.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["comicID"]))
{
    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
    $checkID = $_POST["comicID"];

    $query = ("SELECT pageLocation FROM page WHERE comicID = '$checkID' ORDER BY pageNum");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    print_r($row["pageLocation"]);
}
else
{   
    $checkID = null;
    echo "Error. No comic found.";
}

?>
```

To my knowledge, loadList.php is working perfectly, so I didn't list its code to keep things relevant.

Comment: Any chance you could dump an example of what comicID is? Just to make sure there aren't any unexpected characters like `"'images/0.jpg'"`

Comment: comicID is generally an integer number. In the test I've been performing the two comicIDs have been '100' and '101'. This extends to the foldernames of the 'comic' containing files (or 'pages'), so an example of the file structure would be:

'comics/100/0.jpg'

Where 100 is the id of the comic and 0.jpg is the file.

Comment: Where are you getting `imgSrc`?

Comment: Apologies, imgSrc was a leftover from previous code until I realised I could directly use 'result' and that 'imgSrc = result' was a waste of time. I'll edit the question to remove it.

Comment: Why are you using an XHR to make an AJAX request, but jQuery to issue a `POST`?

Comment: I was going to update the XHR at some point, I haven't got round to it yet. I know it probably looks odd but it's mostly functional at the moment except for the image source problem.

Comment: I only need the first row, that's actually intentional. For some reason "SELECT FIRST (pageLocation)" didn't seem to work.

Comment: You're going to want to `echo json_encode()` that associative array response

Comment: Ok, I've added json_encode().

Comment: `$row["pageLocation"]` is a single result. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns only one row and iterates to the next one every time you call it. You'll need to use a while loop to get every result, or use `mysqli_result::fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.

Comment: PHPglue, I've explained already that I only need the first result anyway. Please stop reposting the same response, this is the third time.

Comment: How does `$row['pageLocation']` parse into an Array of Objects that have a `comicID` property? That would be a single database column entry `pageLocation` from the first result row.

Comment: comicID is a foreign key in the page table if that helps.

I need whatever the first result is from a list of pages sorted by pageNum, because I always want to use 'page 1' (i.e. the comic cover) for display in a thumbnail image.

Comment: If you're using jQuery there is no need for a raw XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and tweaked it a little so I could run it without the web services and it works great. Here is the HTML page I created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<script>

    // JSON parsing for 'loadComic'.
    function loadComicJSON()
    {
        var arr = [{comicID: 1},{comicID: 2},{comicID: 3}];
        var result = "monkey.jpeg";
        var i;
        var out = "";

        document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML="";

        if (arr.length == 0)
        {
            //Irrelevant manipulation of HTML.
        }
        else
        {
            out+="<br>";

            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                out += "<hr><br><img name = '" + ('cm' + arr[i].comicID) + "' id='" + ('com' + arr[i].comicID) + "' onclick='resizeThumb(this)' height='100px;' src='' ><input name='comicList' type='radio' id='" + arr[i].comicID + "' value='" + arr[i].comicID + "'>" + arr[i].comicName + " </option><br><br>";
            }


            document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML=out;
            for(j=0; j< arr.length; j++)
            {
                var imgSrc;
                tempID = (arr[j].comicID);
                document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML+="<p>"+result+"</p>";
                document.getElementById("com"+arr[j].comicID).src = result;

            }

        }

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loadList"></div>
<button onclick="loadComicJSON()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I created an array of JSON objects that hold the comicID and am statically creating the image as 'monkey.jpeg'.

The code works so there is either an issue with the 'response' that you pass into your loadComicJSON method or the result from your POST method.

Add a couple of console.log statements and look at the two values I mentioned and you will likely see the issue.

Comment: Ok, I'm apparently getting "comics\/100\/01.jpg" instead of "comics/100/01.jpg" as the result. (extra forward slashes, for some reason).

Comment: @alex494 then use `unescape()` to remove those extra slashes. `var source = "comics\/100\/01.jpg"; var new_source = unescape(source);`

Comment: @alex494 updated comment. `new_source` should be a string without those extra slashes.

Comment: unescape() doesn't seem to alter it.

Comment: result.replace("\", "");

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting empty image tags but the backslash issue is sorted.

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to debug your code in something like Chrome developer tools and see what is going on. The code is ok but the data you are expecting isn't quit right womewhere. I am not sure there is much more we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue myself. It turned out that the $.post needed to be  $.get and that it needed to technically be outside of a loop (i.e. in its own function) to work properly. Works fine now after that and a couple minor tweaks.